# How to make text fit to area text box in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text

I am using variables in Illustrator CC.

As the text comes into my design, I want the font size to change to make the text fit, without the size of the text area box changing.

So, a short word that comes from the variable might have a font size of 14, but a long word that comes in to the same box from the variable would have a font size of 8. Whatever font size lets the word fit in the text box.

Thank you

Comment: It could be scripted but it would take some hours (for me at least). I could manually scale many words during those hours. What is your case? Do you have many many words?

Comment: Hi @Mads, yes, I have many many words, need an automated solution to work with the rest of the automation using variables.

Comment: I have come across the term OVERSET TEXT and I think that is what my case is referring to. Although still searching for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Overset text is when there is not enough room in the textbox for the text contained. The part of the text not shown is the overset text. Illustrator warns you with a red +.

Comment: From a user-experience point of view, that's a less-than-optimal solution.  *Much* less.   It would be far better to size the type for the longest word and simply allow the whitespace to vary.

Comment: Similar question (minus the variables)... [Is there a quick/easy way to scale one line of text to match another in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46107/is-there-a-quick-easy-way-to-scale-one-line-of-text-to-match-another-in-illustra/46111#46111)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script and technique described in the [LinkedIn article here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adobe-illustrator-variable-data-dealing-overset-text-vasily-hall).
The method there would be to add the referenced script be ran during your batch export actions process. To have it run during your batch action, it's got to reside in the [Menu > Scripts] menu item.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it.  It'll look terrible and your users won't like it.  Size the text for the longest word, and let the whitespace vary naturally.

Comment: Whilst true in most cases I don't think you can say this without knowing the context. There are definitely valid reasons to do this

Comment: @Cal:  what valid reasons would those be?  I've been around quite awhile and can't imagine any such reasons, but I'm always happy to learn.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/mvyas91/type-stacking/

Comment: [What is this “justified” text technique called?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46855/what-is-this-justified-text-technique-called)

Comment: @Cal:  I don't think 19th c. poster design is what's being talked about here.  The OP's aim is to resize individual words appearing at different times, not filling up a space with a message of some sort.

Comment: Nothing I linked to is limited to the 19th C, it's a common use now and you have no idea in what context or why OP is asking this. The GDSE question I linked is talking about infographics — a perfect use case for using variables; which is the only context OP gave. Like I said, I completely agree with you in most cases but the fact is there are perfectly good reasons to do what OP wants.

Comment: @Cai: *So, a short word that comes from the variable might have a font size of 14, but a long word that comes in to the same box from the variable would have a font size of 8.*  Sounds t'me as though they come at different times and are not co-resident.  Perhaps the OP will be good enough to clear up the misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't know why you're arguing. All I said is that there are valid use cases for doing what OP wants. Second guessing what OP may possibly be doing to lead to this question and saying "don't" isn't really an answer.

Comment: @Cai:  And I asked you for examples and you provided ones that don't seem apposite to me.  Why do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Hi @MMacD and Cai, The words do come from variables, and they do come at different times. In more detail, so you understand the context, it is part of a school project, with jars of jam, using the web, customers make their own jam mixes (different fruits) and this app creates the label output as a PDF ready for print.  Example, the branding on the label will remain the same, the flavour of the jam will change [VARIABLE] Fruit Jam, would read "Strawberry Fruit Jam" or "Apple Fruit Jam". In this example, strawberry font size would need to be smaller than apple. Hope that clears it up. Thanks.